# Android, Kotlin, Place view dynamically between two other dynamic views

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing a program in which input fields are added at the push of a button and the content of the field is stored in a view model (code already works for this)

Since the individual views with the text fields are steps of a tutorial, I want to implement a way to add forgotten steps in between.

For a better visualisation of the whole:
at the position of the red line(example), another view should be inserted, which also has its content at the same position in the view model.(within the list of steps)
[image]

How can I implement this in Kotlin, so that I have a function (with input of the desired position of the view), which moves the view to the desired position in the linear layout?

My code:
AddStepsFragment:

```
lateinit var btnAddStep : MaterialButton
lateinit var llList: LinearLayout
lateinit var model : AddNewRecipesViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    model = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[AddNewRecipesViewModel::class.java]

    llList = view.findViewById(R.id.llList)//Linear Layout that contains the steps

    btnAddStep = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddStep)
    btnAddStep.setOnClickListener {
        addStep(null)
    }

}

private fun addStep(string: String?) {

    val row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.steps_row, null)

    val ilDescription = row.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.ilDescription)
    if(string != null) ilDescription.editText?.setText(string)
    ilDescription.editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            //model.updateStep()
        }

    })

    val btnRemove = row.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnRemoveStep)
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener {
        model.removeStep(ilDescription.editText?.text.toString())

        llList.removeView(row)
        llList.children.forEachIndexed { index, view ->
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvStep).text = (index + 1).toString()
        }
    }

    val tvStep = row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvStep)
    tvStep.text = (llList.childCount + 1).toString()

    llList.addView(row)
}
```

AddNewRecipesViewModel:

```
    private val _stepsList: MutableLiveData<List<String>> = MutableLiveData()

val stepsList: LiveData<List<String>>
        get() = _stepsList

fun addStep(step: String) {
    val list = _stepsList.value?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()
    list.add(step)
    _stepsList.value = list
}

fun removeStep(step: String) {
    val list = _stepsList.value?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()
    list.remove(step)
    _stepsList.value = list
}
```